# Get the value of a local variable into the controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JS file containing a controller and other functions structured like this:

```
class RandomCtrl {
    constructor(randomService) {
    this.randomService = randomService;
    ...
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);
    }

    ...

}

function getData(RandomCtrl) {
    ...
}


function getChart(data) {
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

    const chartOptions = getWeekHourlyOptions(data);

    const allCols = [].concat(chartOptions.dataColumns);
    allCols.push(["x"].concat(_.map(chartOptions.xAxis, element => moment(element).valueOf())));
    const xVals = xAxisValues(chartOptions.xAxis);

    ...
}

...

RandomCtrl.$inject = ['randomService'];

export const Random = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<',
        siteNames: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: randomPageHtml,
    controller: RandomCtrl
};
```

I want to get the value of `allCols` from `getChart()` into the Controller.

I've tried to add it in `$onInit` like `this.allCols = getData.allCols` but it doesn't work. Probably not the right way.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Where are you calling `getChart`? and why do you need to pass controller to a method?

Comment: `allCols` is a local variable inside that method, I want to be able to use it outside of its method also. The data contained in this variable is  used to populate a chart, a chart can be shown or not if you click somewhere. When the chart must be shown again, I need the data from `allCols`, that's why I need that information outside `getChart()`

Comment: `allCols` has type `const` you can't replace it with a new array/value

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare **allCols** as a global variable and populate the data in **getChart()**
2. send **allCols** in **getChart()** as return value so that whenever this method is called the return value can be stored into another variable and can be consumed